# Same seaborn plots with different data names

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I need to generate multiple heatmaps using seaborn. All plots have the same format and the only difference is data names (Pandas data frames), and I’m looking for a way that is simpler than using multiple, similar lines. Let's say I want to generate 5 heatmaps from 5 dataframes (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5). Below is what I tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1=pd.read_excel('c:/temporary/df1.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('c:/temporary/df2.xlsx')
df3=pd.read_excel('c:/temporary/df3.xlsx')
df4=pd.read_excel('c:/temporary/df4.xlsx')
df5=pd.read_excel('c:/temporary/df5.xlsx')

for group in [‘df1’, ‘df2’, ‘df3’, ‘df4’, ‘df5’]:
   fig = plt.figure()
   x_labels = ['apple','orange','kiwi'] 
   y_labels = ['1','2','3'] 
   ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.25,0.25,0.7,0.7]) 
   ax=sns.heatmap(f’{group}, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax1)
   fig.savefig(f'c:/temporary/{group}-matrix.png')
```

It didn't work I guess because f'{group} cannot be a dataframe, but are there any ways similar to this instead of writing 5 similar lines like below? Thanks in advance.

```
ax=sns.heatmap(df1, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax1)
ax=sns.heatmap(df2, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax1)
ax=sns.heatmap(df3, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax1)
ax=sns.heatmap(df4, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax1)
ax=sns.heatmap(df5, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax1)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the actual objects?  Loop over `[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]` instead - the group is the actual dataframe. If you need a name to it, `zip` it with a name? (`enumerate` then to number the files? As you want) Or store the dataframes df1 to df5 in a dictionary - a name to object mapping, and iterate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, then it looks like a case of simply changing your list `[‘df1’, ‘df2’, ‘df3’, ‘df4’, ‘df5’]` with a list of variables `[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]` and then changing the
`f’{group}` with `group`